# Error decoding JSON - keyNotFound(CodingKeys

Tags: json, swift, decoding

When I try to decode this json:

```
"polls": [
{
  "title": "title",
  "date": "date",
  "summary": "summary",
  "stats": {
    "total": {
      "dagegen gestimmt": 139,
      "nicht beteiligt": 114,
      "dafür gestimmt": 454,
      "enthalten": 2
    },
  }
}, /*<and about 76 of this>*/ ]
```

with this Codable:

```
struct poll: Codable {
  var stats: stats
  var title: String?
  var date: String?
  var summary: String?

  struct stats: Codable {
      var total: total
      struct total: Codable {
          var nays: Int
          var yays: Int
          var nas: Int
          var abstentions: Int

          private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
             case yays = "dafür gestimmt"
             case nays = "dagegen gestimmt"
             case nas = "nicht beteiligt"
             case abstentions = "enthalten"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I get the following error 
`keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "dagegen gestimmt", intValue: nil)`(if you need the full error text tell me)

I tried some of the answer from similar questions but nothing worked.

Comment: In the other 76 of those objects, do all of them have the keys `dagegen gestimmt`, `dafür gestimmt`, `nicht beteiligt` and `enthalten`?

Comment: Yes, please add the *full error* message. And name structs with starting capital letter to avoid confusion like `var total: total`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apparently have occurrences of `total` where `dagegen gestimmt` is absent. So, make that an `Optional`, e.g. `Int?`:

```
struct Poll: Codable {
    let stats: Stats
    let title: String?
    let date: Date?
    let summary: String?

    struct Stats: Codable {
        let total: Total

        struct Total: Codable {
            let nays: Int?
            let yays: Int?
            let nas: Int?
            let abstentions: Int?

            private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case yays = "dafür gestimmt"
                case nays = "dagegen gestimmt"
                case nas = "nicht beteiligt"
                case abstentions = "enthalten"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I’d also suggest the following, also reflected in the above:

- Start type names (e.g. your `struct` names) with uppercase letter;
- Use `let` instead of `var` as we should always favor immutability unless you really are going to be changing these values within this `struct`; and
- If your date is in a consistent format, I’d suggest making the `date` a `Date` type, and then you can supply the `JSONDecoder` a `dateDecodingStrategy` that matches (see sample below).

---

For example:

```
let data = """
    {
        "polls": [
            {
                "title": "New Years Poll",
                "date": "2019-01-01",
                "summary": "summary",
                "stats": {
                    "total": {
                        "dagegen gestimmt": 139,
                        "nicht beteiligt": 114,
                        "dafür gestimmt": 454,
                        "enthalten": 2
                    }
                }
            },{
                "title": "Caesar's Last Poll",
                "date": "2019-03-15",
                "summary": "summary2",
                "stats": {
                    "total": {
                        "dafür gestimmt": 42
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    """.data(using: .utf8)!

struct Response: Codable {
    let polls: [Poll]
}

do {
    let decoderDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    decoderDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    decoderDateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

    let userInterfaceDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    userInterfaceDateFormatter.dateStyle = .long

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(decoderDateFormatter)
    let response = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
    let polls = response.polls
    for poll in polls {
        print(poll.title ?? "No title")
        print("  date:", poll.date.map { userInterfaceDateFormatter.string(from: $0) } ?? "No date supplied")
        print("  yays:", poll.stats.total.yays ?? 0)
        print("  nays:", poll.stats.total.nays ?? 0)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

That produces:

```
New Years Poll
  date: January 1, 2019
  yays: 454
  nays: 139
Caesar's Last Poll
  date: March 15, 2019
  yays: 42
  nays: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your model as per following format. Also check datatype as per your response.

```
struct PollsModel:Codable{
    var polls : [PollsArrayModel]

    enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey{
        case polls
    }

    struct PollsArrayModel:Codable{
        var title : String?
        var date : String?
        var summary : String?
        var stats : PollsStatsModel

        enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey{
            case title
            case date
            case summary
            case stats
        }

        struct PollsStatsModel:Codable{

            var total : PollsStatsTotalModel

            enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey{
                case total
            }

            struct PollsStatsTotalModel:Codable{

                var dagegen_gestimmt : Int?
                var nicht_beteiligt : Int?
                var dafür_gestimmt : Int?
                var enthalten : Int?

                enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey{
                    case dagegen_gestimmt = "dagegen gestimmt"
                    case nicht_beteiligt = "nicht beteiligt"
                    case dafür_gestimmt = "dafür gestimmt"
                    case enthalten = "enthalten"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```